# EmbedScriptFromFile & RunScriptFromFile - QTP/UFT

Tags: javascript, qtp

Please help me in using `EmbedScriptFromFile` & `RunScriptFromFile` for executing JS file in QTP/UFT.

I'm trying to fetch N number of values using JS file, and receive the same in QTP/UFT in an array. For which, I have got to know about `EmbedScriptFromFile` & `RunScriptFromFile` in QTP/UFT help section. But when I've tried to use the sample code, I couldn't make it as expected. Please help me in this issue

Java Script code I'm using:

```
function cloneArray(arr) {
          var ret = [];
          for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i)
          ret.push(arr[i]);
       return ret;
 }
```

VB Script, I'm using:

```
Browser("Home").Page("Home").EmbedScriptFromFile "C:\Users\Gopi\Desktop\CloneArray.js" 'Call the function and run the script that returns the array'
Set cloned = Browser("Home").Page("Home").RunScriptFromFile("cloneArray(C:\Users\Gopi\Desktop)")
```

Getting some errors while executing these two line - for first line, I'm getting error as 'Object doesn't support this property or method'. And for the second line, I'm getting error as 'The parameter is incorrect'. Please help

---

`15-Dec-2014:` I have tried the suggestions below and it worked! But on top of that, I'm trying to get the array values too from JavaScript function.

**Code to create an array:**

```
function makeArray() {
    var myArray = new Array(4);
    for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++){
        myArray[i] = i+1;
    }
    return myArray;
}
```

So exactly what I'm trying to achieve is, execute `makeArray()` function to create an array and create the QTP/UFT supporting array using `cloneArray` method by passing the `makeArray()` returning value/array as parameter to `ConeArray(arr)`. But when I try to achieve this with following code, I couldn't make it.

```
Browser("Home").EmbedScriptFromFile "C:\Users\Gopi\Desktop\cloneArray.js"
'Set arr1 = Browser("Home").Page("Home").RunScriptFromFile "C:\Users\Gopi\Desktop\makeArray.js"
Set arr = Browser("Home").Page("Home").RunScript("cloneArray[C:\Users\Gopi\Desktop\makeArray.js]")
For i = 0 To arr.length - 1
    msgbox i & ": " & arr.item(i)
Next
```

`EmbedScript` & `RunScript` are working fine when I try separately, but not able to use while trying to pass another function as parameter.

I have tried to have both the functions in same JS file and call the functions, and tried with a few other possibilities too. But nothing helped, so please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all we should understand the `RunScript` and `EmbedScript` functions (and their `FromFile` variants).

- `RunScript` is a method of `Page` and `Frame` and it accepts a JavaScript and executes it, returning the result of the script (typically the last expression run).
- `EmbedScript` is a method of `Browser` and it means *"make sure that this script is run on all `Page`s and `Frame`s of this `Browser` from now on"*. This function returns no value since its main purpose is to run in the future (although it also runs immediately on the `Page` and existing `Frame`s currently in the `Browser`). `EmbedScript` can be used in order to make a JavaScript function available for future `RunScript` use.

The plain versions of these functions accept some JavaScript script while the `FromFile` variation takes a file name (either on the file system or in ALM) and reads that file.

**Regarding your question** - on your second line you're preforming a `RunScriptFromFile` but aren't passing a file name, you seem to be passing a script (for this you should be using `RunScript`). Additionaly the parameter you're passing  to `cloneArray` is not an a valid JavaScript value.

If you want it to be a string you should put it in quotes, in any case it looks like you're expecting an array so perhaps you meant to do this:

```
Set cloned = Browser("Home").Page("Home").RunScript("cloneArray(['Users', 'Gopi'])")
```

In any case it's problematic to pass JavaScript arrays into VBScript, the `.length` property works fine but indexing into the array is a problem (perhaps due to the fact that JavaScript uses square brackets while VBScript uses parentheses).

A workaround for the array problem could be something like this

```
// wrapArray.js
function wrapArray(array) {
    return { 
        length: array.length,
        item: function(index) {
            return array[index];
        }
    };
}
```

Then you can use the following in UFT/QTP.

```
Browser("B").EmbedScriptFromFile "C:\wrapArray.js"
Set arr = Browser("B").Page("P").RunScript("wrapArray(['answer', 42])")
For i = 0 To arr.length - 1
    Print i & ": " & arr.item(i)
Next
```

**Output:**

> 0: answer
>   1: 42

Comment: Yeah, it worked fine. But I couldn't make it when I try to pass another function as parameter - please refer to the `15-Dec-2014:` section in main question for detailed information and help me plz.

Comment: You can't pass a file's path as a parameter to a function, I'm guessing your trying to do `Browser("Home").Page("Home").RunScript("cloneArray(makeArray())")` Now that the `makeArray` function is defined you can call it.

Comment: I've created one JS function with some AJAX code to call servlet component.

And named that function as `'ajaxFunction()'`, but when I try to call this function as discussed here `Browser("Home").Page("Home").RunScript("ajaxFunction()")`, I'm getting error as **'Access Denied'**.

I'm completely new to AJAX, just by the basic search I understood like it's nothing but _Asynchronous JavaScript and XML_, and it's something similar to JS! And so QTP probably would support it, but confused with this error. So please confirm whether QTP could read and process AJAX code or not, & guide me to use it.