# touchscreen activity identification using UFT

Tags: touchscreen, hp-uft

need help to solve a problem.
I have an application running via UFT which is a simple web based app. I am connecting my laptop to a touchscreen monitor so that my boss can check the progress being shown in that application using a simple touch and navigation rather than using mouse clicks.

I need to display a specific view for 10 mins and if I dont get any touch activity on the screen in those 10 mins I need to change the view and go to the next page. if there is an activity on the application (simple scroll or click or zoom in) then I need to wait 10 more mins and then go to the next page. How do I accomplish this using UFT? How do I tell UFT that there was an activity on the application and hence 'dont' go to the next page for 10 more mins?

All the objects on the page are normal UFT identifiable objects like Weblink, WebElement etc but the activity can even happen just on the broser (if user decides to just zoom in - the way it happens on any smartphone)

Please help me by giving some pointers.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really something that UFT is intended to do but it can be achieved by using UFT's [`Browser.EmbedScript / RunScript`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27441810/3848)  functionality.

Put the following code in a JS file (e.g `C:\timeStamp.js`).

```js
['touchstart', 'touchmove', 'touchend', 'touchcancel'].forEach( function(eventName) {
    window.addEventListener(eventName, function () {
        window._lastTouchEvent = new Date().getTime();
    }, true);
});

if (!window._lastTouchEvent)
    window._lastTouchEvent = new Date().getTime(); // Initialize to when the script was loaded

function minutesSinceLastTouch() {
    var diff = new Date().getTime() - window._lastTouchEvent;
    return diff / (60 * 1000); // Convert MS to minutes
}
```

Now the function `minutesSinceLastTouch` is available for `RunScript` to use.

```vbs
Browser(B).EmbedScriptFromFile "C:\timeStamp.js"
elapsed = 0 ' How much time since last touch
Do While elapsed < 10       
    Wait (10-elapsed)*60 ' Wait till 10 minutes after last touch
    elapsed = Browser(B).Page(P).RunScript("minutesSinceLastTouch()")                   
Loop
Print "Loop exited, move to next page"
```

Comment: That's a clever idea @Motti

Comment: hi Motti, Sorry I m writing after a lot of gap on the same subject however I am having little trouble to execute this whole thing. I tried your suggestions and kept the jscript separate and ran my QTP code. Now, the 'elapsed' value that is returned is always more than 10 no matter if I click on the screen or not. I tried this multiple times and everytime the 'elapsed' value is in the range of 11 to 55. I am doing anything wrong in this case? I think I want 'elapsed' to return value which is less than 10 if I click on the screen even once during the 10 mins wait but that's not happening.

Comment: @VishalBorgaonkar, I don't know, I would add some `console.log`s to troubleshoot the problem.

Comment: upon further research I realized that the script doesn't identify the 'touch' activity and only calculates the time since start of the script till you stop it. So basically when I run just this much code, if I don't touch or perform any activity for 40 mins, the 'elapsed' value that the java script returns is 40. However if I touch the screen every min during 10 mins and stops the script immediately after 10 mins are over, I get the returned value as 10.24/10.25 (which is precisely the time since the script started)