# Accessing the properties of an Object that resides in another Object

Tags: javascript, vbscript, qtp, hp-uft

I am using UFT and VBS and I am getting an object from a JavaScript command that returns other objects, but I am unable to access these objects properties.

In detail:

1. I run in UFT a command that returns all the data from a `SlickGrid` table. The command is `grid.getData();` and returns an object.
2. This object is set to object variable `objListArray` and the hierarchy is:

> ```
> objListArray (Object)
>       |
>       |---0 (Object)
>       |        |
>       |        |---Property1 : Value
>       |        |---Property2 : Value
>       |        |---Propertyx : Value
>       |        
>       |---1 (Object)
>       |        |
>       |        |---Property1 : Value
>       |        |---Property2 : Value
>       |        |---Propertyx : Value
>       |
>       |---2 (Object)
>       |        |
>       |        |---Property1 : Value
>       |        |---Property2 : Value
>       |        |---Propertyx : Value
>       |
>       |---n (Object)
>                |
>                |---Property1 : Value
>                |---Property2 : Value
>                |---Propertyx : Value
> ```

No matter what I tried I cannot access the properties of the objects.
Any ideas how I can access these properties? I am limited to VBS as this is for a UFT script.

So far I tried without success:

```
objListArray(0).Property1   '--> Generic error

For Each x in objListArray  '--> Object does not support that
```

various other combinations that return a generic error.

Comment: Have you tried something like `Set obj = objListArray(0)` and then `obj.Property1`?

Comment: Indeed I tried... Getting again 

Unknown runtime error
Line (24): "Set obj = objListArray(0)".

Start to believe that this cannot be managed with VBS and UFT.

Comment: Can you check if array functions still work correctly? For example `objListArray.shift().Property1`?

Comment: What is the actual type of `objListArray`? (`WScript.Echo TypeName(objListArray)`)

Comment: -Chris C: This function is available and working ok
-Ansgar Wiechers: The type Object is JScriptTypeInfo

After finding the type that is still a JavaScript object I manage to access it. Please see my answer bellow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized that the object is of type JScriptTypeInfo

In order to access it I can use the bellow:

```
objListArray.[0].Property1
```

Now, to iterate through the Object you can do it like that:

```
For i = 0 To objListArray.Length-1
    x =  eval("objListArray.[" & index & "].[Account Number]")
    'Do anything you want with x
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a problem with accessing JavaScript arrays in UFT, please see [my answer to another such question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27441810/3848).

I seem to remember that UFT have solved the problem themselves so try using `.item`, if that doesn't work you can try the suggestion from my aforementioned answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think it could be a collection of dictionary objects (dictionary within dictionary).

Try to access this way.

`objListArray(0)("Property1")`

Or

`objListArray(0).Item("Property1")`